# Why random write of numpy array element is much slower than random read?

Tags: python, numpy, numba

The following code is part of an image binarization algorithm. I am trying to improve the performance of this algorithm, but I find the bottleneck in a strange place. (Irrelevant parts of the algorithm are omitted.)

```
@jit(nopython=True)
def make_buckets(img):
    height, width = img.shape

    buckets = np.zeros(256) 
    # buckets = np.full(256, 0) [I tried both, sometimes one works better than other]

    for h in range(height):
        for w in range(width):  
            g = img[h, w]
            a = buckets[g] + 1
            # buckets[g]  = 1
            # buckets[g]  = a

img = np.random.randint(0, 256, (224, 224))
%timeit make_buckets(img)
```

The runtime of the above code is:

```
539 ns ± 12.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

which is fine. It means that, getting/accessing `buckets[g]` inside a loop is not demanding at all. Let's see what happens if I uncomment this line: `buckets[g]  = 1`

```
    for h in range(height):
        for w in range(width):  
            g = img[h, w]
            a = buckets[g] + 1
            buckets[g]  = 1
            # buckets[g]  = a
```

The runtime is,

```
27.8 µs ± 865 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

This means setting `buckets[g]` inside a loop increases runtime drastically.

Now, if I uncomment the `buckets[g]  = a` line like this:

```
    for h in range(height):
        for w in range(width):  
            g = img[h, w]
            a = buckets[g] + 1
            # buckets[g]  = 1
            buckets[g]  = a
```

The runtime increase to:

```
37.8 µs ± 1.09 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

This increment of runtime is consistent, and depending on the `img` matrix, it can take >100 µs. This also means that setting matrix element to a variable is much slower than setting it to a constant. Can someone explain why setting the matrix element to a variable in a loop increases runtime so drastically? Also, can you suggest fs there is any way to improve the performance than this?

*I am doing machine learning with millions of images (of handwritten documents), so my datagenerator should be fast enough so that it does not bottleneck the GPU. In the datagenerator pipeline, there are multiple image manipulations, so I want to optimize each operation as much as possible. This binarization is done on every image, so I want to bring down the runtime to a few microseconds.*

Comment: Keep in mind that numpy arrays use a static data type, unlike a python list or variable.  For this reason, setting elements from a python variable requires safety checks / conversions, and so we would expect this to take somewhat more time than reading an element which already has an enforced type.  I do not know however if this accounts for the entire difference you see here, or if other factors are at play.

Comment: If all you're doing is reading, those reads can be optimized out. Try actually *doing* something with the data you're reading, something that can't just be optimized away.

Comment: @HymnsForDisco, Indeed, when I tried using python list `buckets = [0 for _ in range(256)]` instead of `buckets = np.zeros(256)`, (and convert the list to numpy afterward) The performance was slightly better, sometimes up to 20%.

Comment: There is a dead code elimination. You don't do anything which affects the output of the function in your first example -> the code is detected as useless and is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can replace your code with this:

```
def make_buckets(img):
    return np.bincount(img.reshape(-1), minlength=256)
```

Please try that and let us know the timings.

Ref: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Unfortunately, it is much slower than the one I'm using. The runtime for this one is - 

`133 µs ± 1.42 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)`

The runtime hovers between 130 µs to 150 µs.